# How to express in Propositional Logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

If A(S;C) is the propositional function (predicate)  and student S who takes course C receives an A grade and the domain is a set of student belonging to university x.

How to express "There are students belonging to x university with all A's" in symbolic form.

I express the basic proposition as `S->C->A`.I need to know whether this is right and also how to express the above condition in symbolic form.

Comment: Must be something like : $\exists s \forall c [(Student(s) \land Course(c)) \rightarrow Grade_A(s,c))]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a question in propositional logic, but predicate logic.

You need to render the claim "There exists a student  S such that for any course C, A(S,C)."

That means using quantifiers.